# Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS 0x0000000282bed12e _CFHTTPServerResponseEnqueue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, cfnetwork

I'm getting a crash, reported in Crashlytics, and I have no idea how to reproduce the error, It happens randomly so it's hard to debug it with Xcode. Any ideas?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be52de8 objc_release + 8
1  CoreFoundation                 0x188485138 -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI dealloc] + 60
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1885c732c __CFBasicHashDrain + 304
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18851aa30 _CFRelease + 220
4  CFNetwork                      0x188d4f0dc _CFHTTPServerResponseEnqueue + 21232
5  CoreFoundation                 0x18851aa30 _CFRelease + 220
6  CFNetwork                      0x188c42090 _CFStreamErrorFromCFError + 3820
7  CoreFoundation                 0x18851aa30 _CFRelease + 220
8  CFNetwork                      0x188c28198 _CFURLConnectionCopyTimingData + 6052
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be34c40 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 112
10 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be4aa04 objc_destructInstance + 88
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be516f8 _objc_rootDealloc + 52
12 CFNetwork                      0x188b726a0 (Missing)
13 CFNetwork                      0x188b723fc (Missing)
14 CFNetwork                      0x188bbdbfc CFURLCredentialStorageSetDefaultCredentialForProtectionSpace + 18196
15 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be34c40 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 112
16 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be4aa04 objc_destructInstance + 88
17 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be516f8 _objc_rootDealloc + 52
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1884bb8f0 __RELEASE_OBJECTS_IN_THE_ARRAY__ + 112
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1884818b8 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 272
20 CFNetwork                      0x188cd54d0 _CFStreamErrorFromCFError + 607020
21 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be34c40 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 112
22 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be4aa04 objc_destructInstance + 88
23 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be516f8 _objc_rootDealloc + 52
24 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be34c40 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 112
25 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be4aa04 objc_destructInstance + 88
26 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19be516f8 _objc_rootDealloc + 52
27 libswiftCore.dylib             0x18c2547c0 (anonymous namespace)::destroyGenericBox(swift::HeapObject*) + 48
28 libswiftCore.dylib             0x18c253714 _swift_release_dealloc + 28
29 Alamofire                      0x103bdf5ac $s9Alamofire16DownloadResponseVyypGWOh + 372
30 libswiftCore.dylib             0x18c253714 _swift_release_dealloc + 28
31 libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x1ce290784 _Block_release + 188
32 libdispatch.dylib              0x1881d2280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
33 libdispatch.dylib              0x18818123c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 896
34 CoreFoundation                 0x188518c30 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
35 CoreFoundation                 0x1885130e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2480
36 CoreFoundation                 0x188512200 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
37 GraphicsServices               0x19e68f598 GSEventRunModal + 160
38 UIKitCore                      0x18addbbcc -[UIApplication _run] + 1052
39 UIKitCore                      0x18ade11a0 UIApplicationMain + 164
40 MyProject                      0x102ffdfb8 main + 19 (AppDelegate.swift:19)
41 libdyld.dylib                  0x1881f1588 start + 4
```

Please help me to find it , what is this error related to and how can i reproduce it and solve it.

Comment: your array memory is deallocated, check your array

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sorry but can you explain little bit more which array you are talking about and how can i check it.

Comment: I am talking about this array `1  CoreFoundation                 0x188485138 -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI dealloc] + 60`